# finding the probability exercise help

Tags: probability

I just started learning permutations and probability and I'm trying to solve this one here.

In the programming division at a local company there are 17 junior programmers and 8 senior programmers. Six programmers are needed to comprise a team for a new project.  The order in which team members are assigned to the project is not important.

How many different teams can be selected?
My Solution:
$_{17} C_9$ / 6

How many different teams can be selected that have equal numbers of junior and senior programmers?
My Solution:
$17!$

How many different teams can be selected such that there are no fewer than 4 senior programmers on the team?
My Solution:
$17!$ / $_{17} C_4$

Am I on the right track with my solutions?

Comment: No, not at all.  You seem to be randomly throwing around factorials and binomial coefficients without stopping to think about what those are used for or represent.  You are also throwing around random numbers that you heard in the problem without stopping to think about what numbers those represent.

Comment: As @JMoravitz said, nothing makes sense. Can you please share how you arrived at those solutions?

Comment: Let's start from the beginning... Some programmers are junior and some programmers are senior.  How many *total* programmers are there?  We want to count how many groups of six programmers we can make using some subset of the combined collection of programmers.  We use binomial coefficients for this... Do you recall what the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ is used to count?  Is that the same type of thing we are trying to count here?  What should be $n$ and what should be $k$ in this case?  $n$ is the total number of programmers we can choose from and $k$ is the amount we are choosing...

Comment: For the second part... if we have picked the same number of junior programmers as we had senior programmers... how many junior programmers did we pick?  How many senior?  How many ways can we have chosen that many junior programmers?  How many ways could we have chosen that many senior?  What do we do with these two numbers?  Recall your [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).  Use the same type of logic for the last part, noting that "at least 4 senior" means "exactly 4 or exactly 5 or exactly 6 senior programmers"

Comment: This question is asking us to debug your reasoning, but you don't explain your reasoning. You should explain the logic behind your results if you are going to ask this kind of question.

Comment: I'm looking at the notes that my teacher gave me and I'm kind of lost.  I was trying to plug in numbers that match his examples...i guess I'm far off the mark :/

Comment: would n = the total 25 programmers and k = 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\binom{n}{k}$ counts the number of ways to form a subset of size $k$ from a set with $n$ elements.  For instance, if you have $20$ players on a team and you want to choose $5$ to play in a practice match, there are $\binom{20}{5}$ ways to pick the players (*where we don't care about what positions each play*).
(*Also sometimes notated as $~_nC_k$, as $C(n,k)$, as $C^n_k$ as $C_n^k$ and others... but these other notations are needlessly confusing since they conflict with other notations and with each other*)

[Rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) loosely states that if you can describe an outcome via a unique sequence of steps such that the number of options for each step remains consistent regardless what choices were made for other steps and each outcome is counted exactly once each in this way, the total number of outcomes will be the product of the number of choices for each step.  For instance, the number of ways to choose an outfit consisting of a pair of pants and a shirt when you have $3$ pants and $5$ shirts to choose from will be $3\times 5$.

[Rule of sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum) loosely says that if we want to count outcomes and we can split them up into disjoint non-overlapping groups we can count each group separately and add the results.  For instance, if we have $3$ pants and $5$ shirts, the total number of pieces of clothing we have is $3+5$.

---

For your problem, we have $17$ junior and $8$ senior programmers.  Altogether we have a total then of $17+8=25$ programmers to choose from.

We want to choose $6$ of these $25$ programmers.  We have **25** and we want to **choose 6**.  We can do this in $\binom{25}{6}$ ways, (*read aloud as "25 choose 6"*)

For the second part, we want to count the number of these ways of choosing six people where we had the same number of junior and senior programmers chosen.  That happens precisely when we had picked $3$ junior and picked $3$ senior programmers each.  Well... we set this up via rule of product by first picking which three junior programmers we used and then which three senior programmers we used.  From the $17$ junior programmers, we choose $3$ of them... and from the $8$ senior programmers we also choose $3$ of them.  These can be separately done in $\binom{17}{3}$ and $\binom{8}{3}$ ways for a combined total of $\binom{17}{3}\cdot\binom{8}{3}$ ways altogether.

For the last part, we want to count the number of these ways of choosing six people where we had more senior programmers chosen than junior.  That happens when we have $4$ senior and $2$ junior, when we have $5$ senior and $1$ junior, or when we had all $6$ being senior and no junior programmers selected.  Count each separately similarly to how we did for the previous part and add the respective cases together.

Comment: That makes way more sense than my notes. Sorry for my crappy solutions but my school building is shut down so I can only come here to get help.